# Create an overview of scattered items / requirement list

Tags: table-of-contents, glossaries, tocloft

I'm writing a document where I have to define **multiple requirements**. These requirements are scattered all over the document, since they belong in different sections and are explained seperately.

It would be good to have a **central overview of all these requirements in one place**, e.g. a table. Unfortunately I can't figure out, how to do this, so I don't have to write the text of the requirement manually into the table (in case I am changing the words in one of them later, it should also automatically change in the overview, similar to a glossary or a ToC).

I already made an own counter, so I don't have to number everything manually, since it's possible that I'm adding a requirement later on. However, I also tried to solve this problem before with an additional glossary, but these packages are quite... difficult to handle for me, so I failed with this approach.

A perfect solution would be, if I just have to write \newreq{Requirement description} and it would generate an automatically numbered output like R01 Requirement description - and in addition I can use a command like \printreqoverview which is printing the table.

Details like formatting or appearance I can modify later, but I am currently stuck with this referencing - and it would really help, since I have to write every description two times and check for spelling mistakes every time - a reference would help.

I'm sorry, I can't describe the problem very well I guess...

I added a minimum working example, which does not contain any referencing, just automatic numbering:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fmtcount}

\newcounter{rcount}
\setcounter{rcount}{0}
\newcommand{\newreq}{
    \stepcounter{rcount}
    \textbf{R\padzeroes[2]{\decimal{rcount}}}
}

\begin{document}

\section{First Chapter}

\lipsum[4]

\begin{enumerate}
    \item[\newreq] This is the first requirement.
    \item[\newreq] This is the second requirement.
\end{enumerate}

\lipsum[4]

\begin{enumerate}
    \item[\newreq] This is the third requirement.
\end{enumerate}

\lipsum[4]

\section{Overview Table}

\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
    \hline
    \# & Requirement \\ \hline
    \hline
    R01 & Text of R01 \\ \hline
    R02 & Text of R02 \\ \hline
    R03 & Text of R03 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a job for the [`tocloft`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tocloft) package.  It allows customizing the printing of the table of contents, list of figures, and list of tables; and also defining new “list of...”s.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fmtcount}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\newlistof{requirement}{lor}{List of Requirements}

\renewcommand\therequirement{R\padzeroes[3]{\decimal{requirement}}}
\newcommand{\newreq}[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{requirement}%
  \par\noindent\textbf{\therequirement. }#1%
  \addcontentsline{lor}{requirement}{\protect\numberline{\therequirement} #1}%
}


\begin{document}

\section{First Chapter}

\lipsum

\newreq{This is the first requirement.}
\newreq{This is the second requirement.}


\lipsum

\newreq{This is the third requirement.}

\lipsum

\listofrequirement

\end{document}
```

The line `\newlistof{requirement}{lor}{List of Requirements}` creates a new “list of”, based on a counter `requirement` (I renamed your `rcount`; LaTeX counters are in a different namespace than other macros so it's not necessary to have `count` in the name).  The list will be generated in a file whose base name is the same as the current job name, and whose extension is `.lor`.  The last argument is the title of the list to be displayed.  This command creates the macro `\listofrequirement`, which you can invoke to print the list.

But writing the list is done on a step-by-step basis, each time a requirement is created.  The text of the requirement is needed as an argument to `\newreq`.  The new `\newreq` command first prints the requirement label, then the requirement text.  (You can customize how you want the requirements formatted.) The `\addcontentsline` command adds a line to the `.lor` file.  After expansion, that line will look like:

```
\contentsline {requirement}{\numberline {R\padzeroes [3]{\@decimal {1}}} This is the first requirement.}{2}
```

You can change the list of requirements to be a tabular, but you will have to make sure the `\begin{tabular}` is written to the `.lor` file at the beginning of the document and `\end{tabular}` at the end.  `\AtBeginDocument` and `\AtEndDocument` can be used here.  But perhaps this is good enough.

Comment: Thanks for the quick and detailed answer. Unfortunately I can't get the tabular to work. I tried: \AtBeginDocument{\addcontentsline{lor}{requirement}{\protect\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}}}
\AtEndDocument{\addcontentsline{lor}{requirement}{\protect\end{tabular}}}
But I'm just getting an error message I don't understand. It would be good to have the page number as a column as well.

Comment: @Lumiukko: You want `\addtocontents{lor}{\protect...}` and not `\addcontentsline`.

Comment: Followup question because of the space problem with the numbers in the list of requirements: [missing spaces with tocloft's \listofrequirement](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/374609/16967)