# missing spaces with tocloft's \listofrequirement

Tags: tocloft

Testing tocloft with [this example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/128025/78614), `\listofrequirement` makes
[image: a list without space between reference and title].

Why ?
(I use lualatex)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: The code is the one of this [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/128025/78614).
As a newcomer, I am not allowed to ask directly in [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128015/create-an-overview-of-scattered-items-requirement-list).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since package `tocloft` is used, the horizontal space for the number is controlled by `\cftXnumwidth`, for example:

```
\settowidth{\cftrequirementnumwidth}{R000}
```

Applied to the example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fmtcount}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\newlistof{requirement}{lor}{List of Requirements}
\settowidth{\cftrequirementnumwidth}{R000}

\renewcommand\therequirement{R\padzeroes[3]{\decimal{requirement}}}
\newcommand{\newreq}[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{requirement}%
  \par\noindent\textbf{\therequirement. }#1%
  \addcontentsline{lor}{requirement}{\protect\numberline{\therequirement} #1}%
}


\begin{document}

\section{First Chapter}

\lipsum

\newreq{This is the first requirement.}
\newreq{This is the second requirement.}


\lipsum

\newreq{This is the third requirement.}

\lipsum

\newpage
\listofrequirement

\end{document}
```

> [image: Last page with list of requirements]